# Limiting hierarchical or PCA input with features with higher standard deviation?

Tags: clustering, pca, standard-error, hierarchical-clustering

Hi if I have a data matrix say a gene array with 30K probes and 8 samples and I want to do some sort of clustering analysis, is it appropriate to first filter the genes with low variation?  For example can I first subset the data with only genes with high standard deviation, say .15?  Would this be a better approach and if so how would I go about choosing the correct standard deviation?

The reason for this is because I wanted to first eliminate genes that are similar across the samples, especially since the matrix can get big  > 800K probes.

thanks!
A.

Comment: Perhaps you should edit in why you want to do this?

Comment: Since PCA identifies where high variation is, it should be fairly insensitive to low variance features.